# Does Entitiy Framework set Default value

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Hi my problem is that my EF 4.0 mapping does not replicate the Default value of some columns.

**For example**
in my Question object i have an int type field Status for which i have set Allow null = false (un-check the allow null checkbox) and set its default value to be 1.

Now the strange behavior is when i insert the record in sql server and doesn't set the status field, it works fine and set the value 1 in record after commit. 
But my entity framework mapping (.edmx file) doesn't set the default value and it says **"Default value = (None)"** in property window.

Is that a known issue or i am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue a few months back and I did not find any easy resolution to the problem.

I can only suggest that you manually decorate your entities from within your edmx or if possible upgrade to EF 6 and use the Code-First from database option which from my experience works much better.